# How to automatically resize an iframe based on browser window width and document length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to create a `frameborder=0` iframe with no scroll bars.

It needs to automatically resize its width based on the browser window's current width.

Its height needs to be based on the `document.length`. So if it's a long page, the iframe needs to stretch way down.

This way, there is no scrollbar created in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myIframe = $(document.frames['idIframe']);

$(document).bind('resize', function() {

   myIframe.attr("width", $(this).width());
   myIframe.attr("height", $(this).height());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573220/how-do-i-refer-to-the-document-object-of-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page-using/1575412#1575412) may have the answer you are looking for...