# Changing the innerHTML of an HTML object with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am loading an external page into an HTML object:

```
var object = document.createElement('object')
object.data = 'myPage.html'
$("#myDiv").html(object)
```

Now I want to modify the source of `object`. But I can't figure out how to use jQuery to access any of the elements of `myPage.html`. For example:

```
$("#myPageDiv").css('background-color', '#000');
```

has no effect. How can I modify the elements within the injected HTML object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery CSS() for dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717257/jquery-css-for-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Use a regular `iframe` element instead of `object` (the result is the same, except you'll have better access to your external document, providing it comes from the same domain as the main page).

Comment: @Teemu I would use an iframe but I am making a chrome extension and it seems to have some funny behavior when using iframes

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question about that "_funny behavior_" ..?

Answer (score 1):

The `innerHTML` of an object is **fallback content**.

It is to be displayed if the external resource the object is loading isn't supported.

Assigning an HTML document's URL to `data` is effectively using the object as an `<iframe>`. You should probably use an iframe instead as they have been consistently supported among browsers for much longer.

Once you recognise you are dealing with a frame, you can [find plenty of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573220/how-do-i-refer-to-the-document-object-of-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page-using) on how to access the content.

Comment: I would use an iframe but I am making a chrome extension and it seems to have some funny behavior when using iframes

Answer (score 0):

You ask " how to use jQuery to access any of the elements of myPage.html"

```js
var object = document.createElement('object')
object.d = '<div id="x">XXX</div>'
$("#my").html(object.d);
$('#x').text("<b>Some</b> new text.");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my">ddd</div>
```

Try this

```
var object = document.createElement('object')
object.d = '<div id="x">XXX</div>'
$("#my").html(object.d);
$('#x').text("<b>Some</b> new text.");
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem to work, and I am not really sure how it is different from the example I gave

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery's `load` method and `css` method should be able to do the trick.

Hence, please try this (for demonstration purpose):

HTML (e.g. **main.html**)

```
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type=button onclick="javascript:step1();" value="(Step 1) Load HTML">

<div id=myDiv></div>


<input type=button onclick="javascript:step2();" value="(Step 2) Change color">


<script>

function step1()
{
$("#myDiv").load('myPage.html');
}

function step2()
{
$("#myPageDiv").css('background-color', '#000');

}

</script>
```

and for the **myPage.html**

```
This is a test
<br>
<div id=myPageDiv>NEED TO CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR</div>
```

You may see a fully working HTML here:

http://www.createchhk.com/so_Jan05.html